# Parsing JSON into individual NSArray elements

Tags: ios, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

My problem is this. When Im parsing my JSON data it is getting returned to me as an NSSArray with one element.  Inside this one element it looks like this:

```
 2015-07-14 20:45:38.467 ICBuses[51840:14872349] Bus Location: {
    agencyname = Cambus;
    agencytag = uiowa;
    color = 00ff66;
    directions =     (
                {
            direction = Loop;
            directiontag = loop;
            stops =             (
                                {
                    directiontitle = Loop;
                    stoplat = "41.659541";
                    stoplng = "-91.53775";
                    stopnumber = 1050;
                    stoptitle = "Main Library";
                },
                                {
                    directiontitle = Loop;
                    stoplat = "41.6414999";
                    stoplng = "-91.55676";
                    stopnumber = 3200;
                    stoptitle = "Studio Arts Building";
                },
                                {
                    directiontitle = Loop;
                    stoplat = "41.66504";
                    stoplng = "-91.54094";
                    stopnumber = 2100;
                    stoptitle = "Art Building";
                },
                                {
                    directiontitle = Loop;
                    stoplat = "41.6662587";
                    stoplng = "-91.5405201";
                    stopnumber = 2106;
                    stoptitle = "Theatre Building";
                },
                                {
                    directiontitle = Loop;
                    stoplat = "41.6679058";
                    stoplng = "-91.5401033";
                    stopnumber = 2120;
                    stoptitle = "Hancher/North Riverside";
                },
                                {
                    directiontitle = Loop;
                    stoplat = "41.6660209";
                    stoplng = "-91.5406198";
                    stopnumber = 2105;
                    stoptitle = "Riverside & River St";
                },
                                {
                    directiontitle = Loop;
                    stoplat = "41.66499";
                    stoplng = "-91.54106";
                    stopnumber = 2101;
                    stoptitle = "Art Building West";
                },
                                {
                    directiontitle = Loop;
                    stoplat = "41.6612";
                    stoplng = "-91.5403422";
                    stopnumber = 145;
                    stoptitle = EPB;
                }
            );
        }
    );
```

I want each block to be in there once element...How do I do this? Below is my coded that parses the data and stores it to an array.

code that stores it to an array:

```
self.routeInfo = [[API sharedAPI] routeInfoAgency:self.routeAgency
                                                Route:self.route];

    self.busLocation = [[API sharedAPI] busLocation:self.routeAgency
                                              Route:self.route];
    NSLog(@"Bus Location: %@", self.routeInfo);
```

Heres the code that gets it from the server and parses it:

```
- (NSArray *) routeInfoAgency:(NSString *)agency Route:(NSString *)route {

    NSError *error;
    NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.ebongo.org/route?format=json&agency=%@&route=%@&api_key=", agency, route];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",requestString, kApiKey]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];

    if (!data) {
        NSLog(@"Download Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error %@", error.localizedDescription] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        return nil;
    }

    NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    NSArray *JSONArray = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"route.directions"];

    return JSONArray;
}
```

I want what is after stops = to be in an array that where each element is a block of directions title, stipulate, stoping, stop number and stoptitle.
Thank you

When I try to use floatValue I get this error: 
{

```
When I do that I'm getting this error {2015-07-15 10:31:05.821 ICBuses[56344:16107040] -[__NSArrayI floatValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f91fb5bdf90
2015-07-15 10:31:05.868 ICBuses[56344:16107040] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI floatValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f91fb5bdf90'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bc53c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010b8ecbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bc5b0ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bbb113c ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bbb0cd8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   ICBuses                             0x000000010958f26e -[MapViewController viewDidLoad] + 3950
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010c17d1d0 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 738
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010c17d3ce -[UIViewController view] + 27
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010c1a2257 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 633
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010c1ae37f -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 386
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010c1aeece -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 43
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010c2f96d5 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 202
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010c0cc9eb -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 536
    13  QuartzCore                          0x000000010b18eed2 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010b1836e6 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010b183556 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    16  QuartzCore                          0x000000010b0ef86e _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
    17  QuartzCore                          0x000000010b0f0a22 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 462
    18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010b0f10d3 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 89
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bb86ca7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bb86c00 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bb7ca33 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bb7c366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010e727a3e GSEventRunModal + 161
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010c04c8c0 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    25  ICBuses                             0x000000010958e2cf main + 111
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010d481145 start + 1
    27  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I think it is because the for loop is saving it as an array with one element.
Any suggestions?

Comment: it may not answer the question but, why don't you use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) it will make the process of calling the web service and the parsing much easier.

Comment: Its my first app and I would like to understand the process.

Comment: You should accept @Dima answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's not an array at all. It looks like it's actually a dictionary. When you log a collection like that you can see dictionaries because they are marked with `{` and arrays are marked with `(`. Based on the structure of your data, something like this should get the correct members:

```
NSDictionary *JSONDict = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"route.directions"];
NSArray *directions = JSONDict[@"directions"];
NSDictionary *directionsDict = directions.firstObject; // seems to be an array with just 1 element.
NSArray *stops = directionsDict[@"stops"];
for(NSDictionary *stop in stops)
{
  NSString *title = stop[@"directiontitle"];
  NSString *stopLat = stop[@"stoplat"];
  // etc
}
```

Comment: what if I wanted to return stop[@"stoplat"]; 
as a float?

Comment: You use the `NSString` conversion methods. You can just do `stopLat.doubleValue` or `stopLat.floatValue`.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, it appears that `[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"route.directions"];` returns a `NSSdictionary`, not a `NSArray`.

```
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                  JSONObjectWithData:data
                  options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                  error:&error];
    NSDictionary * directions = [json valueForKeyPath:@"route.directions"];
    NSArray * stops = [directions valueForKeyPath:@"stops"];
```

You can then iterate through the `stops` array.